# Power BI - Slicer Color change based on data value

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting, slicers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9pDx.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB0u1.png)I want to change the tile color of a horizontal slicer based on a table value. I.E. if the data value in a table is > 0, format the slicer tile to change color.

In my report I use a simple slicer to drill down on a table below. I essentially want the slicer to highlight if there is a difference between the baseline and database value.

I can use conditional formatting and get the table values to change color, however I am unable to get the linked tile in the slicer to change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by providing the code itself, a [mcve]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot for the question on your post?

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, I've included a screenshot example to support the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power BI, the `Slicer` visual doesn't have any conditional formatting option for the slicer tile color.
But there is an alternative to it. It is to use Power BI `Treemap` visual.

- Slicer
  [image]
- Treemap
  [image]

Comment: Thank you. Using the tree map was a suitable alternative.